# Android - Learning Java

Tags: java, android

I want to find some resources about java programming for android. I have a little knowledge on java programming so the guide have to begin from novice.

In other words i need a tutorial/ebook to learn java programming that i can use latter for android development.

Can you suggest me something that you have read or you know that it is good ? Anything.. from amazon...or anywhere..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info first, then http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Wikibook on Java programming, available free online. [This blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/02/java-good-parts-version.html) lists the various pieces of Java you really need to know to get into Android development, with links to the corresponding Wikibook section.

Answer (score 2):

I can highly recommend this tutorial series.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your knowledge of other languages. If you know C# or C++, Java is not that big issue.

Try to work through an Android app tutorial like this:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

I managed to write my first app as a c# developer with that tutorial

Comment: I know C. C++ not so good.. So i want something really novice..:) Is it worth to learn programming in java from beginning  or not ? Also i begin with this tutorial yeserday and i realize that i cannot understand the code perfect..so thats why im looking for something more novice.. that explains the code and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you only have experience in C, you should first read a bit about the OOP concepts in general because having a firm theoretical understanding of object-oriented programming is crucial to learning any OOP language (Java in your case, C#, Ruby..). 
For example, check this : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Generally, for Java resources you should visit(The Site Formerly Known as java.sun.com).]

Best, 
Jas.